Neural network for complex-valued data
I have some complex data, and I want to teach a neural network to perform certain operations on it.
Now, since Tensorflow does not allow complex inputs, I separated my data into real and imaginary parts and created two models, one for each part. Then, I combined the outputs of both models which gave me the correct result.
However, I am interested in finding out if there is a more efficient approach I can follow here or if there is some other programming language that can handle complex inputs.

Cross-posted on Data Science: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/130109/73930

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
